# pass a javascript function onto native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to pass a javascript function from React Native onto iOS Native components such as a UIButton and execute there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but using events and not by sending JS to native components. Check out [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html#other-ways-of-cross-language-interaction-events-and-native-modules) for detailed information, but generally:

> React Native enables you to perform cross-language function calls. You
>   can execute custom native code from JS and vice versa. Unfortunately,
>   depending on the side we are working on, we achieve the same goal in
>   different ways. For native - we use events mechanism to schedule an
>   execution of a handler function in JS, while for React Native we
>   directly call methods exported by native modules.

Comment: It worked. And it seems that `onChange` property that you add to your class for event bubbling is a preserved name and you cannot rename it to something else. (I might be wrong..)